# Laravel serve ports keep changing

Tags: php, laravel, server, localhost, web-development-server

I'm developing an Api on Laravel that worked fine yesterday but today when i tested a feature, it said Api resource not found then I discover that per request, the port that artisan is served from changes and so the resource not found error any help would be appreciated.
I use Laravel 9 and php 8
below is the terminal log

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Jul 25 16:23:04 2022] PHP 8.0.6 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Mon Jul 25 16:24:47 2022] 127.0.0.1:64765 Accepted
[Mon Jul 25 16:24:47 2022] 127.0.0.1:64765 Closing
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:07 2022] 127.0.0.1:55203 Accepted
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:11 2022] 127.0.0.1:55203 Closing
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:12 2022] 127.0.0.1:55208 Accepted
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:13 2022] 127.0.0.1:55208 Closing
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:14 2022] 127.0.0.1:55209 Accepted
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:14 2022] 127.0.0.1:55209 Closing
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:15 2022] 127.0.0.1:55210 Accepted
[Mon Jul 25 16:37:16 2022] 127.0.0.1:55210 Closing
```

each request from postman changes the port and so postman can't respond, any help is appreciated

these are the defined routes in my laravel routes/api.php file

```
Route::prefix('user')->group(function(){
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register','verify' => true]);
Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::post('email/verification-notification', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'sendVerificationEmail'])->middleware('auth:sanctum');
Route::get('verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [EmailVerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify')->middleware('auth:sanctum');
});
```

then i made this call in postman which would work before

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/register
```

now it returns

```
 "message": "API resource not found",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php",
    "line": 1143,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\helpers.php",
            "line": 44,
            "function": "abort",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\routes\\api.php",
            "line": 46,
            "function": "abort"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 244,
            "function": "{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteFileRegistrar",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php",
            "line": 214,
            "function": "runCallable",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 725,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceJsonResponse.php",
            "line": 20,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\ForceJsonResponse",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 126,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 726,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 703,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 667,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php",
            "line": 656,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 141,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\HandleCors",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 39,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 180,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php",
            "line": 116,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 142,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\public\\index.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\boka\\Mop\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\resources\\server.php",
            "line": 16,
            "function": "require_once"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: _"the port that artisan is served from changes "_ No. The site is served from port 8000. That other changing port number is the source port from the client side and _should_ change. This is unrelated to your error.

Comment: what statement can i use there to better convey the message because the other clients wont let me request to them throws an error saying connectionrefused

Comment: You can't make a request from the server to the client. The client makes a request to the server, from a random port to port 8000, and then the server responds on that same connection.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the code or commands you're running which are giving errors, and the exact errors you're getting. You may also want to explain what you're trying to do, because as Alex Howansky says, it sounds like you don't have a clear understanding of how HTTP models requests and responses.

Comment: i understand that and have been doing these for a while.. this just started today and a first encounter for me

Comment: This is a server-side application error and it has nothing to do with any ports. I'm not terribly familiar with Laravel but it looks to me like your route is `/user/register` and not `/api/user/register`. The `NotFoundHttpException` exception is essentially a 404 -- you're asking for a page that doesn't exist.

Comment: Laravel prefixes an /api to all api routes so /user/register wouldn't work, only /api/your route would work so web routes and api routes are differentiated